# Ошибка MS SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, 1с

При создании документа "Ведомость в банк"
При подборе документов, послу нажатия на кнопку выбрать появляется ошибка

> Невосстановимая ошибка Ошибка при выполнении запроса POST к ресурсу
>   /e1cib/logForm: по причине: Ошибка СУБД: Microsoft SQL Server Native
>   Client 11.0: Столбец или параметр #3: указанная точность столбца 44
>   превышает максимальную допустимую точность 38. HRESULT=80040E14,
>   SQLSrvr: SQLSTATE=42000, state=1, Severity=10, native=2750, line=1

Конфигурация зарплата и управление персоналом 3.1.6 
Платформа 8.3.12

Как можно исправить этот момент?

Comment: Ну как вариант, открыть базу в ms sql и изменить размерность указанного типа для столбца, ну например с nvarchar(100) на nvarchar(MAX)

Comment: А вообще, можно снчала через профайлер посмотреть что вообще происходит.

Comment: @QuaternioNoir FYI: "открыть базу в ms sql и изменить размерность указанного типа для столбца" = нарушение лицензионного соглашения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была в платформе, в агрегатных функциях
стояла платформа 8.3.12
я понизил до 8.3.11

всё заработало

Comment: Можно по подробней где изменить?

Comment: Платформа 1С стояла 8.3.12.1440 я её удалил и поставил 8.3.11. Не стал химичить с SQL. (Ошибка была в агрегатных функциях самой платформы)

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка возникает в Общем модуле УчетНДФЛ. В функции РассчитатьУдержанныеНалоги.  Я взял её из предыдущего релиза 3.1.6.6 и всё заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Профайлер выдает ошибку при исполнении SQL скрипта над базой tempdb: 
CREATE TABLE #tt84 (_Q_001_F_000RRef BINARY(16), _Q_001_F_001RRef BINARY(16), _Q_001_F_002 NUMERIC(44, 0), _Q_001_F_003 NUMERIC(44, 0))

SQL, соответственно, ругается (у меня SQL Server 2008 R2).
Возможно на более поздних версиях SQL проглатывает эту ошибку.

Comment: У меня Windows Server 2016 + SQL Server 2016 - Полет нормальный, но только на платформе 8.3.11

Answer (score 0):

В релизе 3.1.7.105 данная ошибка исправлена. Видимо учли проблемы платформы.